# I need to prove that exists a homomorphism uniquely determined in a exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence

[image: Here is the picture of the sequence]

I have the next sequence where the row is exact, A, B, C and D are $R$-Modules and $ h \circ f =0$.  I need to prove that exists a homomorphism $k: C \to D$ uniquely determined such that $ k \circ g = h$

Comment: You might check out my answer to your other question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607250/proof-about-exact-sequence.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$h$ "factors through" $g$.  This is completely analogous to the *first isomorphism theorem*.

Given $c\in C$, define $k(c)=h(b)$, where $b$ is any element of $g^{-1}(c)\ne\emptyset$.  One can check that this is a well defined homomorphism, using the exactness.

I think you could probably call this a "universal property of exact sequences".  It could also probably be phrased in terms of "uniqueness of final objects" in category theory, but I am not prepared to do that right now.